# Linux cat and less output for my text file is different from gedit and other gnome editor

Tags: linux, text, terminal, editor, gnome

**I redirected ri's ruby Array doc into a file but it didn't look good in gedit. But text looks just fine in cli. That's how my file looks in terminal editors. Everything is fine here.**

```html
= Array#to_param

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_param()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Calls to_param on all its elements and joins the result with slashes. This is
used by url_for in Action Pack.


= Array#to_query

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_query(key)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Converts an array into a string suitable for use as a URL query string, using
the given key as the param name.

  ['Rails', 'coding'].to_query('hobbies') # => "hobbies%5B%5D=Rails&hobbies%5B%5D=coding"


= Array#to_s

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s(format = :default)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


= Array#to_sentence

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_sentence(options = {})

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**But when I open it in gedit or other gnome editors, that's how it looks like. Some specific words look in absurd format. Any suggestions or help will be appreciated.**

```html
= AArrrraayy##ttoo__ffoorrmmaatttteedd__ss

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_formatted_s(format = :default)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Extends Array#to_s to convert a collection of elements into a comma separated
id list if :db argument is given as the format.

  Blog.all.to_formatted_s(:db)  # => "1,2,3"
  Blog.none.to_formatted_s(:db) # => "null"
  [1,2].to_formatted_s          # => "[1, 2]"


= AArrrraayy##ttoo__ppaarraamm

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_param()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Calls to_param on all its elements and joins the result with slashes. This is
used by url_for in Action Pack.


= AArrrraayy##ttoo__qquueerryy

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_query(key)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Converts an array into a string suitable for use as a URL query string, using
the given key as the param name.

  ['Rails', 'coding'].to_query('hobbies') # => "hobbies%5B%5D=Rails&hobbies%5B%5D=coding"


= AArrrraayy##ttoo__ss

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s(format = :default)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


= AArrrraayy##ttoo__sseenntteennccee

(from gem activesupport-5.1.3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_sentence(options = {})

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I tried opening it into every system. but text is still messed up everywhere except terminal editors like cat or less.**
Does it have anything to do with text encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ri` outputs documentation formatted as `ASCII text, with overstriking`. You can check this by running the `file` command on your file.

Some parts of the documentation are bolded, which is represented by some character, backspace (`^H`) and the first character again. It seems that gedit and other gnome editors ignore these backspace characters, leaving the actual character repeated.

You can output just the ASCII like this:

`ri Array | col -bx > array.txt`

An answer with more information about `nroff` formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274795

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked!!! I also started looking into ri's man page and found that you can change output format using -f option. So, ri -f rdoc Array > array.txt works too.